# "?feed=rss2" in Pagination URL

Tags: structure, pagination, ce-cache, zoo-triggers, ab-pagination

I have a blog listing set up with Structure, Zoo Triggers, AB Pagination, & CE Cache. Here's an abridged version of the template:

```
    {exp:ce_cache:it}
        {embed='_embeds/document_head'}

        {snippet:header}

        {exp:channel:entries
            channel='blog'
            dynamic='no'
            disable='member_data'
            limit='10'
            {triggers:entries}
        }
            {if count == 1}
            <ul class="vertical-block entries resetlist">
        {/if}

          <li class="clearfix">
            {!-- Entry Data --}
          </li>

        {if count == total_results}
          </ul>

          {snippet:pagination}
        {/if}
      {/exp:channel:entries}

      {snippet:footer} 

      {exp:minimee:js}
        {snippet:global_scripts}
      {/exp:minimee:js}

        {snippet:document_foot}

    {/exp:ce_cache:it}
```

And the pagination snippet:

```
{paginate}
  <div class="pagination">
    <ul class="resetlist">
      {if abp_has_previous}
        <li>
          <a href="{abp_previous_link}">&laquo;</a>
        </li>  
      {/if}
      {abp_pages}
        <li{if abp_is_current} class="current"{/if}>
          <a href="{abp_link}">{abp_num}</a>
        </li>
      {/abp_pages}
      {if abp_has_next}
        <li>
          <a href="{abp_next_link}">&raquo;</a>
        </li>     
      {/if}
    </ul>

    <p>Page {abp_current_page_num_liber} of {abp_total_pages}</p>
  </div><!--/.pagination-->
{/paginate}
```

So occasionally when you advance to the next page in the listing using pagination, the URL looks like this: `/blog/?feed=rss2/P10` and breaks pagination.

Clearing/disabling CE Cache fixes the problem, but I'm not sure if it's a CE Cache problem or AB Pagination or what. There is a link to an RSS feed on the page, but its url is `feeds/blog`, not a query string.

- EE 2.5.5
- Structure 3.3.8
- CE Cache 1.9.2
- Zoo Triggers 1.1.13
- AB Pagination 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kgrote, try and download the latest release of AB Pagination from devot-ee, there was a bugfix about a month ago dealing with this issue.

Also, if you're interested in passing that ?feed=rss2 query string with the pagination links you can use the {abp_query_string} variable, more info here: https://getsatisfaction.com/addonbakery/topics/does_not_work_with_query_strings#reply_6709038

Comment: Thanks for the response Bjørn! I updated AB Pagination and so far the problem hasn't occurred again. I'll mark this as the answer and post directly in AddOn Bakery support if I have any more problems.

Comment: Darn, still happening. I'll open a ticket over at AddOn Bakery.

Comment: So I thought I downloaded the latest version from Devot:ee, but I just checked and I'm still running v1.6.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "breaks pagination"? EE might think that string is an extra segment. Our official support is available here: https://structure.tenderapp.com

Comment: When I say it "breaks pagination", I mean the template doesn't advance to the next 10 listings, but rather displays the first 10 again. I didn't post this on your official support because I'm not entirely sure Structure has anything to do with it. But I really have no idea. To be honest CE Cache is my #1 suspect.